# upload a file and obtain its file name and save it to database that is in pgsql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

in index.js file i have given

```
router.post('/postfileupload',User.postFileUpload,function(req,res,next){
    User.postFileUpload(req,res);
});
```

and in user.js I have provided the function definition as:

```
function postFileUpload(req,res){
  if(req.files)
    console.log('request for fileupload \n ',req.files);
}
```

and while running the code i get the error 
"Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]"

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be `if(req.files)` in postFileUpload, not `res.files`

Second, `postFileUpload` function does not return anything to the user and does not call `next()`. Change it to:

```
function postFileUpload(req, res, next){
  if(req.files)
    console.log('request for fileupload \n ',req.files);
  next();
}
```

Third, your other middleware function, which also calls `User.postFileUpload` for some weird reason (do you even need to call that function twice?), also doesn't return anything to the user. Change it to something like:

```
function(req,res,next){
    res.status(200).send('OK');
}
```

In short, your router should look like:

```
router.post('/postfileupload', User.postFileUpload, function(req,res,next){
    // Do whatever you want to do here
    res.status(200).send('OK');
});
```